# Issue - Importing data from mysql to HDFS

Tags: mysql, hadoop, import, sqoop

I am trying to import a table "employee" from MySQL(installed on my laptop) to HDFS(on VM placed on my laptop as well)

I have given all permission to MySQL as well .. using following command successfully

grant all privileges on *.* to root@192.168.56.1 IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;

what may be the problem ..

please help !!

Following error is coming

```
[edureka@localhost sqoop-1.4.4]$ bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.1/test --table employee --username root -P --target-dir /out/10sep/sq1 -m 1Warning: /usr/lib/hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Enter password: 
15/09/15 13:40:31 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
15/09/15 13:40:31 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
15/09/15 13:41:34 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:357)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2482)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2519)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2304)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:801)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:660)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:683)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:240)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:223)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:347)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1277)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1089)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:396)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:502)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:307)
    ... 32 more
15/09/15 13:41:34 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1095)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:396)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:502)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

Comment: are you able to connect to MySql from your VM using command-line ?
what is output for ? 

mysql --host=192.168.56.1  --database=test    --user=root

Comment: tried to run your command from vm ... no joy

Comment: so it failed ?  you received any error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQOOP execute a MapReduce job to work in parallel. The question is: Are all your hadoop nodes able to communicate with MySQL ? In your example you are only granting access to the DB to one host. Is your hadoop "cluster" a standalone instance ?

Comment: This was it. I was using an SSH tunnel and using `-R 3306:localhost:3306` to map port 3306 on the Hadoop node connecting to my local MySQL server. By default SSH only allow localhost connections to remotely mapped ports, so the other nodes could not connect! I had to use `-R 10.0.0.x:3306:localhost:3306` after adding `GatewayPorts yes' to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config/` (and restarting `ssh` service.)